# Load table from CSV in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datatables

I'm trying to upload a csv file into a table in a Oracle database. I've used the following command line:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_x (codice varchar(100), descrizione varchar(300), tipo varchar(100), macroarea varchar(100), includere varchar(100));

LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/-/Documenti/Tabelle_per_App/OK/REPARTI_modifiche.csv' into table tmp_x field terminated by ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" (codice, descrizione, tipo, @vmacroarea, includere) SET macroarea = NULLIF(@vmacroarea,'')
```

no error appears, but the table remain empty.
I need to do it with a command line query, without creating external tables.
Thanks a lot.

| CODICE | DESCRIZIONE | TIPO | MACROAREA | INCLUDERE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C19 | COLLABORATORI COVID19 | I |  | NO |
| CCV | COVID COLLABORATORI VACCINATI | E |  | NO |
| CET | CONTROLLI ENDOSCOPIA TORACICA | I |  | NO |
| CGF | CHIRURGIA GEN. FAMILIARI | I |  | NO |
| CHL | CHIRURGIA PLASTICA - FAMILIARI | I |  | NO |
| CKM | CHECK UP S MARCO | I |  | NO |
| CPR | POSTRICOVERO CARDIOLOGIA | I |  | NO |
| CSF | CHIRURG.SENOLOGICA - FAMILIARI | I |  | NO |
| CTF | CHIRURGIA TORACICA - FAMILIARI | I |  | NO |
| CVF | CHIRURG.VASCOLARE - FAMILIARI | I |  | NO |
| D0800 | Cardiologia | I | MEDICA | SI |
| D0900 | Chirurgia Generale | I | CHIRURGICA | SI |
| D090003 | Chirurgia Plastica | I | CHIRURGICA | SI |
| D090010 | Chirurgia Senologica | I | CHIRURGICA | SI |
| D130000 | Chirurgia Toracica | I | CHIRURGICA | SI |
| D1400 | Chirurgia Vascolare | I | CHIRURGICA | SI |

Comment: For me, that's not enough info. I'd like to see CREATE TABLE, sample CSV data (a few lines) and complete .CTL file.

Comment: You can add a small representative sample of your CSV data to the question (as formatted text). That way, we don't need to rely on an external link.

Comment: Please, do as Andrew says. Me (and probably some other community members) either don't have access to sites like that, or don't want to access it for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you wish to create an external table. If such be the case, then please read https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i for instance.
Or, you may create a table in Oracle (not external) using the plain create table command, like the one you gave, after which you load data from the .csv file using sqlldr. For sqlldr, read: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html#GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144

Comment: I don't have the permission to create external tables.